# Может ли транслятор работать без интерпретатора или компилятора?

Tags: компилятор, интерпретатор, транслятор

Может ли транслятор работать без интерпретатора или компилятора и почему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если придерживаться самых распространенных определений транслятора, интерпретатора и компилятора, то да.

`Транслятор` - переводчик с какого-то языка на другой язык.
`Компилятор` - переводчик на некий низкоуровневый язык, в форму подлежащую исполнению. Например в машинный код
`Интерпретатор` - штука которая программу сразу исполняет. Например на некоторой виртуальной машине, а виртуальная машина уже на лету компилирует в машинный код.

То есть штука, которая нашу программу переводит скажем с паскаля на javascript, это транслятор, но не компилятор. Если конечно наша машина не предназначена для исполнения сразу javascript.

Вообще все эти три понятия на практике очень взаимосвязаны и переплетаются.

Answer (score 2):

Да, может работать.

Транслятор - это техническое средство, выполняющее трансляцию программы. То есть переводит текст программы с одного языка на другой, не более.

Компилятор - это тот же транслятор, только переводит код с языка высокого уровня на язык низкого уровня. Поскольку компилятор, это транслятор, то первая часть вопроса не имеет смысла.

Интерпретатор исполняет код программы, для транслирования он не нужен.